# Rename comments labels in WP admin

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to change default comments in wordpress admin?

I`d like to rename *comments* into *testimonials* everywhere in admin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change all WordPress uses of 'Comment', then you need to hook into the translation filter

```php
is_admin() && add_filter('gettext', function ($translation, $text, $domain) {
    if (strpos($translation, 'comment') !== FALSE) {
        return str_replace('comment', 'testimonial', $translation);
    }
    if (strpos($translation, 'Comment') !== FALSE) {
        return str_replace('Comment', 'Testimonial', $translation);
    }

    return $translation;
}, 10, 3);
```

But that changes EVERYTHING that runs through `gettext`.
If you just wanted to change the admin section title you would do this:

```php
add_action('admin_head', function () {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    if (!empty($wp_meta_boxes)) {
        foreach ($wp_meta_boxes as $page => &$positions) {
            foreach ($positions as $context => &$priorities) {
                foreach ($priorities as $priority => &$boxes) {
                    foreach ($boxes as $id => &$box) {
                        if ($id === 'commentsdiv') {
                            $box['title'] = 'Testimonials';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Beyond that, you'd have to find every instance of 'Comment' and see if there was an associated hook for that situation. I'm not sure if that is feasible.